# Razor clams good or bad?

Tags: food-safety, seafood

I bought some razor clams today and all of them were open with their "tongue" or meat coming out of the shell.  When I got home I noticed they had a really strong smell to them. This is the first time I've bought razor clams....so how do I know if they are safe to eat?

Answer (score 6):

There are two types of razor clams.  Since you are in the US according to your profile, I am guessing you have the type from the Pacific Northwest, which look like this (picture from Washington Fish and Wildlife):

[image]

It is normal for the razor clam to not completely fit into its shell; in particular, the digger or "foot" will extend from the shell.

According to [Piscatorial Pursuits](http://www.piscatorialpursuits.com/cleaningclams.htm) (I couldn't make that name up):

> The neck tips are very tough and give off a very strong scent.

[The Washington Department of Fish and Wildlife](http://wdfw.wa.gov/fishing/shellfish/razorclams/clean_prepare.html) has a detailed page on cleaning and preparing the clams, with pictures.  Note that they indicate (emphasis original):

> During cleaning, you may find small "pea crabs" or flatworms inside
>   the body of the clam. NEITHER OF THESE AFFECTS THE QUALITY OF THE
>   RAZOR CLAM MEAT.

Comment: Interesting. I'm from the east coast of the US, and to me, [this is a razor clam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_jackknife_clam).

Comment: @JoeFish That is the kind that my research indicated was common in England.